# Copy value of cell to another cell to record vehicle mileage

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a spreadsheet to record vehicle mileage.  I'd like to manually enter starting mileage in F6 and ending Mileage in G6.  I'd like the value of G6 to then automatically be copied to F7 and I'd enter the ending mileage in G7- and so on.  The problem I have is dealing with weekends and holidays when 2 or 3 blank cells may occur. I've tried using something like `=if(D9=""," ", G6)`, but this doesn't work.

I've also tried this function in VBA:  `=IF(D9=""," ",LastNonBlankCell(G8:G39))` [D9 is a datefield] and only ended up with 0's.

```
Function LastNonBlankCell(Range As Excel.Range) As Variant

    Application.Volatile

    LastNonBlankCell = Range.End(xlDown).Value

End Function
```

Comment: Please show a screenshot (or text representation) of the scenario you're having an issue with (the sequence of days followed by blanks for the weekends), with the expected calculated values filled in (even if faked).  Thanks.

Comment: Agree with gmm that you need to give us more detail on what you are expecting to happen. However, don't you just need the *maximum* value in column G, rather then the value in the last non-blank cell in G? The most recently entered ending mileage will always be greater than the previous ones (unless you get a newer car!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the blank rows for weekends or holidays? If not, set `D8` to the formula `=workday.intl(D7,1)` then copy it down as far as needed. If you need to allow for holidays, see the Excel documentation for `WORKDAY.INTL`. The list of dates will now contain only workdays, so the ending mileage for one row can be copied down to the next with no special handling.

This makes weekends and holidays harder to see at a glance. That can be addressed using conditional formatting. Setup formatting for the range `D8:D<whatever>`, use the formula `=D8>(D7+1)`, and set the formatting to whatever stands out for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following VBA macro will achieve your end goal in a slightly different way than what you asked about.

After you have installed the macro, when you double-click on a cell in column G, the macro will copy the last entered ending mileage to the cell to the left in column F.

For example, if the last ending mileage entry was in cell G6 and you double-click in cell G9, that entry will be copied to cell F9. You can then enter the new ending mileage in cell G9.

```
  Private Sub WorkSheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

     If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
        Selection.Offset(0, -1).Value = Selection.End(xlUp).Value
     Else
        Exit Sub
     End If

  End Sub
```

To install the macro, right-click on the worksheet's name tab, select "View Code", and paste in the macro code. It won't work if you put the code into a regular module.